# How to copy data from macro enabled Excel workbook to another Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to copy data from macro enabled Excel sheet to simple Excel file.
But following code is throwing error like object not found.

I am writing VBA code in sheet having one more macro for some other functionality.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 
    Workbooks("JHG raw data.xlsm").Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:D300").Copy_
    Workbooks("JHG summary.xlsx").Worksheets("Data").Range ("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Are both workbooks open in the same Excel instance when you run that code?

Comment: Yes both workbooks are opened in the same excel instance when i run the above code.

Comment: maybe just a typo but `.Copy_` must have a space before the underscore `).Copy _`

Answer (score -1):

Put `Destination:=`     after Copy

```
Workbooks("JHG raw data.xlsm").Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:D300").Copy _
        Destination:=Workbooks("JHG summary.xlsx").Worksheets("Data").Range ("A1")
```

Comment: This code `.Copy_` is not valid. You need a space before the underscore `.Copy _` or it will not compile. And then it will also work without `Destination:=` this is defenitly not needed at all.

Comment: oh yeah I thought destination is always required. Thanks @Pᴇʜ